# <content> tag not rendering depending on placement in template

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm not sure what is happening but the content in the < content> tag is not being rendered depending on where the element is.

My element in use:

```
<my-element>
    <p>Hello There!</p>
</my-element>
```

In my polymer element:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">

    <template>
        <!-- works here -->
        <div>
            <!-- works here -->
            <div>
                <!-- not work here -->
                <content></content>
                <div>
                    <!-- not work here -->
                    <div>
                        <!-- not work here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </template>
```

Its seems like there would be no reason why it would not work. I've been hours on this. Not sure what it could be. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/283. It's been fixed but hasn't made it to a stable release yet.